# PostgreSQL - Joining a table to itself

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Does PostgreSQL support self joining or is there another way to solve this?

For example, lets say I have a single table (table `a`) with the following columns:

```
id     name     supid
------------------------
1       a         2
2       b         3
3       c         4
4       d         5
..      ..        ..
```

Is there a way to output the data in the following format?

```
id      name     sup name
-------------------------
1        a        b
2        b        c
3        c        d
4        d        ..
..       ..       ..
```

Comment: Please be more specific on your question names in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple `JOIN`?

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,b.name "sup name"
FROM tablea a
JOIN tablea b
  ON a.supid = b.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5a200/2).

Comment: I HAD ONLY 1 TABLE i.e.., tablea, I HAVE TO GET THE OTHER TABLE AS the output by checking there supervisors id...

Comment: @RobinHood's: There is only one table here, Joachim is just joining it to itself (hence the two aliases).